# How to handle single ASYNC task class for more number of Activities with showing progress bar in android?

Tags: android

I need to use a single AsyncTask for a multiple Activities and a ProgressBar has to be displayed before getting the data from a server.

Is it possible?

Comment: Create a common class and extend `AsyncTask` in it. and call that class with context of other classes in which you want to use `AsyncTask` class...

Comment: I have written an example on how to use single async through different activities. You can get some help from here https://xelsoft.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/asynctask-implementation-using-callback-interface/

Comment: i need to create progress bar..

Answer (score 0):

I will do it via listeners.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<...>{
    private MyTaskListener listener;
    public void setListener(MyTaskListener l){this.listener = l;}

    //do in background and publish progress
    doInBackground(){
        publishProgress(someProgress);
    }

    onProgressUpdate(int progress){
        listener.onProgressUpdated(progress);
    }

    public interface MyTaskListener {
        void onProgressUpdated(int progress);
    }
}
```

Then implement the MyTaskListener in your activities, and pass it to MyTask:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.setListener(this);
task.execute(...);
```